# How to fill Sms data in notification

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying twilio services and sending notification works fine but I can't set up the sms fallback properly as this is not really documented.

```
HashMap<String, Object> smsNumbers = new HashMap<>();
smsNumbers.put("?", "?");
LOGGER.debug("Adding SMS fallback to: {}", smsNumbers);

LOGGER.debug("Calling sendNotification to {}", identity);
Notification notification = Notification
    .creator(twilioServiceSid)
    .setBody(message)
    .setData(data)
    .setIdentity(identity)
    .setSms(smsNumbers)
    .create(restClient);
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Parameter 'Sms' contains unrecognized property.
at com.twilio.rest.notify.v1.service.NotificationCreator.create(NotificationCreator.java:316) [twilio-7.15.1.jar:]
```

How to fill the HashMap ?

Comment: You can pass null to setSms. It will works

Comment: Check this page https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When setting data that will be sent over SMS channels from a notification, you can set any of the following keys to override the general notification: `body`, `media_urls`, `status_callback`, and `max_price`.

So, if you wanted to send an alternative body over SMS, you would use the following code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> smsNumbers = new HashMap<>();

smsNumbers.put("body", "This is just for the SMS notifications");

LOGGER.debug("Adding SMS fallback to: {}", smsNumbers);


LOGGER.debug("Calling sendNotification to {}", identity);
Notification notification = Notification
    .creator(twilioServiceSid)
    .setBody(message)
    .setData(data)
    .setIdentity(identity)
    .setSms(smsNumbers)
    .create(restClient);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok to be sure I understand it clearly. In case the push notification fails, the notification will be sent over SMS using optionnal body put in the HashMap ? To which telephone number will the SMS be sent ?

Comment: That's not what's going to happen in this case, no. You are choosing an identity to send messages to. Currently, while in public beta, Notify supports the [fan-out orchestration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify#orchestrations) which will send the notification to each binding that you have associated to that identity. [More orchestrations including retries and fallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify#orchestrations) will be launched as the product matures. This code allows you to send a different message to bindings with telephone numbers to other notifications.